# Creating a form / profile in asp.net mvc in Visual studio 2015 connecting to a sql database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

Cant seem to find anything online about this...maybe a form or profile is not the right word to use.
Basically I have connected up my sql db to visual studio 2015 as a model, the data is set up in star schema structure with foreign and primary keys.
I want to create a form like the one below.

The fields in the form come from various different tables, this is the sql code i qould need to use to list these out:

```
SELECT C.Title
,C.Forename
,C.Surname
,C.Postnominal
,C.Degree
,C.Picture
,C.Video
,B.Department
,B.JobTitle
,C.BiographyShort
,C.BiographyLong
,C.HowCanHelp
,D.ResearchArea
,E.ResearchProject
,S.ResearchPersonalID
,U.URL
,U.LABEL
  FROM [StaffProfilesTest].[dbo].[FactStaffProfiles] A 
  INNER JOIN [dbo].[DepartmentJob] B ON A.DepJobID=B.DepJobID
  INNER JOIN [dbo].[PersonalDetails] C ON A.PersonalID=C.PersonalID
  INNER JOIN [dbo].[ResearchArea] D ON D.RAreaID=A.RAreaID
  INNER JOIN [dbo].[ResearchProject] E ON E.RProjID=A.RProjID
  INNER JOIN [dbo].[StudentSupervisor] S ON A.SSID=S.SSID
  INNER JOIN [dbo].[CustomURL] U ON U.UrlID=A.URLID
 -- where c.username=@Username
  GROUP BY  C.Title
,C.Forename
,C.Surname
,C.Postnominal
,C.Degree
,C.Picture
,C.Video
,B.Department
,B.JobTitle
,C.BiographyShort
,C.BiographyLong
,C.HowCanHelp
,D.ResearchArea
,E.ResearchProject
,S.ResearchPersonalID
,U.URL
,U.LABEL
```

This is my entity view in visual studio 2015.
[image]
I have created an mvc asp.net web app.
I have added this as the model.
If i want to create the below form, how would i script this in the controller as action to display all these fields, I am database developer so this is new to me, I am used to sql commands....

I have created two views already but they only look at a single table, my issue is looking at a join of tables.

I am thinking of doing this by creating a view in ssms so i can get all the fields i need will do this via joins within the sql statement, bringing it through in the model in visual studio and then creating controller and view for this. would this be right?

Has any videos or can anyone help with this....

[image]

Comment: Your question is very broad. Did you work trough a MVC tutorial to learn how to create a view from your data? [Getting Started with ASP.NET MVC 5](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started)

Comment: In a simple case, you can use the DisplayFor helper instead of EditorFor in order to make a field display-only. If you have rules about which fields are read-only in different circumstances then it gets a bit more complicated. Maybe ask a bit more of a specific question with some details about exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: have edited question to make it more specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you use entity framework it can generate the views and controllers automatically for you.

If you don't use it, you can still watch a tutorial on it and write the gaps manually so you will have the idea how to do this. It is really simple to do, but you are generally asking to write it for you.

The basic concept is, to create a single viewmodel that contains all of your needed objects, pass it to the view through the controller. On the view it will have all the validation rule from the viewmodel and with jQuery it will set up browser side validation if you use the proper html helpers to create the form.
When you are submitting your form, just expect the same viewmodel, check for its valid state and if it is valid, just save it with your db solution.

On the [asp.net website you can find full tutorials](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started) how to do this, also there is a more explanatory project [called MVC music store](https://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/) .

Also consider writing CRUD business layer, to have the smallest objects to work with. In this way you can abstract away all the complexity and you can create your viewmodels to get the job done. Search for Domain Driven Design for more details. It looks complex but helps a lot.

Comment: Thank you for this, I have edited my above question to give you more of a feel of what i am after. I am having a n issue with joining the tables into one view....hope this helps

Comment: Wow that is huge. Try to separate your objects in a C# model and write the sql in a CRUD format for each. Then you can create a ViewModel in C#. Basically it is a container obejcts with all of your needed objects on the view. It is honestly slower, because you have to make more request to the db than with one large query, but it is more manageable, so you can actually work with it.

Comment: Try to note solve complex problems in sql only, because you will have an unmanageable code, that will be prone to errors  .

Comment: Thank you again, I just want to display these fields in a form, how do I show this in a view, what would I write in my action?

Comment: These are nicely demonstrated on those 2 tutorials that I gave you.